# How to write an if statement which look like the SQL IN clause?

Tags: java, if-statement, expression

Is there any better way of writing the following expression like IN clause in SQL?

```
int x;
if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x ==3 || x == 4 ...)
{
 //Doing something useful 
}
```

I want to write something like below:

```
 if (x in (1,2,3,4,...)) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just go with the `if`.

But since you asked, this springs to mind

```
int x = 3;
if(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).contains(x)) {
//whatever                
}
```

Note this will work for most datatypes that have a valid `equals` method

```
String  x = "foo";
if(Arrays.asList("lol","bar","st0le","foo").contains(x)) {
//whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> values; // list of values in the IN clause
int i = 5;  // value to compare
if (values.contains(i)) {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: A HashSet or TreeSet might be better (if there are a lot of numbers)

Comment: Sure, it's early and I just wanted to get something up there.  You get the idea.  It's likely to be a micro-optimization, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
public class InClause {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x =3;
        if (in (x, 1,2,3,4)) {
            System.out.println("Wh00t");
        }
    }
    public static <T> boolean in(T candidate, T...collection) {
        for (T t : collection) {
            if ((candidate == null && t == null)|| (candidate != null && candidate.equals(t))) return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about check in another way:

```
if(x<=4 && x>0)...
```

Comment: I was not searching for range value. it's more like 
  String x 
  if (x.equals("cat") || x.equals("dog"))

Comment: @BalamuruganK then you need a collection for your candidates. then using contains, like other suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array of the objects and use:

`java.util.Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(obj) > -1`

if the array is sorted then you can do a search

`java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(array, obj)`

returns: index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the potential values of `x` into a `List`.

```
List<Integer> list = ...

if(list.contains(x)) {
    // Do something
}
```